# How to connect IMAP using AUTHENTICATE PLAIN correctly?

Tags: imap

I'm using OpenSSL to connect to mail server.

POP3 works fine but I have problems with IMAP. Based on CAPABILITY command server supports PLAIN, NTLM and GSS-API authentication methods.

I want to use PLAIN because it's easier than others.
I have read it's needed to use `<NUL>` for it.

I have run the next variations, but no success:

```
? login user pass
? login <nul>user<nul>pass
? <nul>login <nul>user<nul>pass
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score -6, accepted):

? login mymailbox@box.zone mypassword\r\n

often servers don't require " @box.zone " part, you can just type login

Comment: Do you know or are you the same person as the OP? I mean, you answer a 6-month old question, using elements of answers that are not even discussed in the question, and it gets accepted within 2 minutes... I don't mind at all if it's the right answer, but it just seems to come out of nowhere.

Comment: Whether the user name should be `mymailbox` or `mymailbox@domain` is purely an administrative/implementation decision on the server side. It tends to be useful for server admins to make their user names be the full e-mail address when the same server is used for multiple domains.

Answer (score 39):

None of the previous answers actually said *how* to use PLAIN authentication, so I did some more digging. It turns out that authentication information is expected in base64. It's probably easiest to explain by example. Assume a username of "bob" and a password of "munchkin".

We'll first need to encode in base64. On a Linux-ish system, it goes likes this:

```
echo -en "\0bob\0munchkin" | base64
```

This incorporates the null characters as required, and also does the base64 encoding. We get this string out: `AGJvYgBtdW5jaGtpbg==`.

Now, we can do the actual authentication (`S` = Server, `C` = Client):

```
S: * OK The Microsoft Exchange IMAP4 service is ready.
C: D0 CAPABILITY
S: * CAPABILITY IMAP4 IMAP4rev1 AUTH=NTLM AUTH=GSSAPI AUTH=PLAIN CHILDREN IDLE NAMESPACE LITERAL+
S: D0 OK CAPABILITY completed.
C: D1 AUTHENTICATE PLAIN
S: +
C: AGJvYgBtdW5jaGtpbg==
S: D1 OK AUTHENTICATE completed
```

And you're done!

Comment: References are [RFC 3501, 6.2.2. AUTHENTICATE Command](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3501#section-6.2.2) for the Base64 requirement and [RFC 2595 6. PLAIN SASL mechanism](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2595#section-6) for the components that needs encoding.

Answer (score 3):

```
May be this will help

/* RFC 4616.2. PLAIN SASL Mechanism.                
The mechanism consists of a single message, a string of [UTF-8]
encoded [Unicode] characters, from the client to the server.  The
client presents the authorization identity (identity to act as),
followed by a NUL (U+0000) character, followed by the authentication
identity (identity whose password will be used), followed by a NUL
(U+0000) character, followed by the clear-text password.  As with
other SASL mechanisms, the client does not provide an authorization
identity when it wishes the server to derive an identity from the
credentials and use that as the authorization identity.

message = [authzid] UTF8NUL authcid UTF8NUL passwd

Example:
C: a002 AUTHENTICATE "PLAIN"
S: + ""
C: {21}
C: <NUL>tim<NUL>tanstaaftanstaaf
S: a002 OK "Authenticated"
*/


IMAP not easy to code, literal string and xxx response formats ... .
It's easier to use some free IMAP client.
```